# Handling desynchronization

Tags: java, android, networking, synchronization

I'm developing a UDP server sided Android game, and there I'm experiencing some design flaws with keeping the clients synchronized. First off, the server sends the game state to every connected client in the game room once an event has been triggered. This broadcast uses a maybe-semantic, which means that the server cannot detect if the client has received the state or not.

The current solution to keep clients with high package loss synced with the server is that every client sends a ping message to the server every five seconds, and if the server detects that the clients last ping message was longer than five seconds ago, it will check if it's connected to a game room, and if it is, send the current game state. This solution is not very reliable since it requires to clients to lose at least two messages (the received game state + the sent ping message).

What would be another, more reliable way of handling desyncs? I've been looking into logical clocks, and thought about implementing a counter in every game room that increments at every event, and then the clients could include the counter in the pings. The problem with this solution is that the ping message architecture at client side is hard to reimplement to support this at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're going to wind up re-inventing most of TCP on your way to solving your problem.  I'm not sure why you chose UDP in the first place, but chances are, you'd be much better off using regular TCP sockets if at all possible.

Comment: I'm not interested in using TCP due to decrease of performance.

Comment: If you haven't already, I highly recommend you measure the actual difference and convince yourself that it really is a show-stopper.  The amount of developer time required to solve the problems of reliable message delivery is immense, and it's very unlikely that the performance difference is worth the extra development time.

Comment: Well, then it all comes down to the current architecture of the server. It is developed with the idea of using a thread pool for every request, it does not directly keep track of the connected clients. I thank you for your answer though.